# Ubuntu 18.04.5 not installing from usb

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, usb

I have downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 in 2019 December and it was booting fine from USB but I lost that iso image hence I downloaded it again from Ubuntu website but now it is not working it is not loading kernel and showing grub command line.
Minimal bash like editing and black screen. But Ubuntu 19.04 and Ubuntu 20.04 is loading.

Comment: Most probably, your downloaded iso for 18.04 is corrupt. See [How to verify your Ubuntu download](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview) or redownload the iso.

Comment: I agree with @kashish, however in my experience the most common failure is the write to install media, which you verify using the *Check disc for defects* option, it's automatically run on 20.04, but requires you to manually start it on earlier releases, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck